# How to convert into dictionary Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to convert this code into comprehension?

```
Dict = {'File': ['lbl101', 0], 'கோப்பு': ['lbl101', 0], 'Alt+1': ['lbl101', 0], 'Accounts': ['lbl102', 1], 'கணக்கியல்': ['lbl102', 1], 'Alt+2': ['lbl102', 1], 'Inventory': ['lbl103', 2], 'சரக்கியல்': ['lbl103', 2], 'Ctrl+3': ['lbl103', 2], 'manufacture': ['lbl104', 3], 'உற்ப்பத்தி': ['lbl104', 3], 'Ctrl+Alt+4': ['lbl104', 3]}


for i,j in dict.items():
        print(i.split("+")[-1])
```

Comment: `Dict = kk {` is not valid Python. And `dict.items()` will give you a TypeError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Just change the loop into [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Also, use lowercase variable names, and use names different from python keywords.

```
dct = {'File': ['lbl101', 0], 'Ctrl+Alt+4': ['lbl104', 3]}
print([i.split("+")[-1] for i, j in dct.items()])
# ['File', '4']
```